# Error 403 when try to POST Data to web services

Tags: web-services, iis, http-post, servicestack

I try to post Data to a remote server (Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS 7), and only one of my class is not working I receive (Error 403), but my data are stored on my sqlite file.

I'm not sure about this part of my code:

```
        public object Post(PatientSessionADD request)
    {
        PatientSessionCRUDFunctions PSCF = new PatientSessionCRUDFunctions(Db);
        PatientDetailsCRUDFunctions PDCF = new PatientDetailsCRUDFunctions(Db);

        // Create the new Session

            // Start Session
            var p = new PatientSession()
            {
                ByPatientId = request.ByPatientId,
                PatientStartSessionTime = request.PatientStartSessionTime,
                PatientStartSessionByUserId = request.PatientStartSessionByUserId
            };

            patientsessionid = PSCF.AddPatientSession(p);

            // --- Generate folder + Images ---
            // Get AgeBlock
            var PatientDetails = PDCF.GetPatientDetailsByID(p.ByPatientId);
            string ageblock = PatientDetails.AgeBlock;
            // Generate path with Session ID
            pdp.GeneratePath(patientsessionid);
            // Call image generator and create images
            TempImageCreationClass.GenerateChartImage(Convert.ToInt32(ageblock));

            // Return a JSON Response
            return new PatientSessionADDResponse 
            {
                PatientSessionId = patientsessionid
            };}
```

When I call my function AddPatientSession directly from my JSON response, I don't get the error 403.
There here my function to ADD Data in the database:

```
public class PatientSessionCRUDFunctions
{
    // The IDbConnection passed in from the IOC container on the service
    System.Data.IDbConnection _dbConnection;

    // Store the database connection passed in
    public PatientSessionCRUDFunctions(System.Data.IDbConnection dbConnection)
    {
        _dbConnection = dbConnection;
    }

    // Inserts a new row into the PatientSession table
    public int AddPatientSession(PatientSession p)
    {
        return (int)_dbConnection.Insert<PatientSession>(p, selectIdentity: true);
    }
}
```

Also when I test my code locally my class is working, so I checked IIS Permissions and I didn't found anything for my issue. it's really confusing because I don't know if the problem is from my code or from IIS.

Do you see what problem it could be? Thanks

Comment: If it's working locally, then the issue is going to be IIS. If you look up error 413 you'll see it's a `Request Entity too Large`, this isn't a ServiceStack error. It likely means your trying to upload large files that exceed a limit set by IIS. [See here for more information](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jiruss/archive/2007/04/13/http-413-request-entity-too-large-can-t-upload-large-files-using-iis6.aspx)

Comment: I'm really sorry @Scott I made a mistake, I get error "403". Sorry about that I what quite tired when I put my question

Comment: Ok I fix the problem with IIS Permissions, Thanks @Scott but why I had this problem (error 403) only for this class. In this implementation I'm getting the ID of a another table to link my tables with a join. I use a function to get it maybe it could be this? If I find the answer I will post it there I'm pretty sure it's not only IIS permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found my problem was about IIS authentication, I enable all kind of authentications, it's probably not the best think to do but I don't get this error anymore. 
[image]

Comment: Activate only "Anonymous authentication" and "ASP.NET Impersonation" is enought